# How does "disableBrowserContextMenu" behave in Viewer3D.js v7?

Tags: documentation, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Please tell me about the behavior of the Viewer3D setting parameter `disableBrowserContextMenu` .
Because it's not in the [API Reference](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#new-viewer3d-container-config). ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhd4P.png))

This [gif animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofY7v.gif) did capture with `{ "disableBrowserContextMenu" : false }`.
If developer want to use context menu of web browser, should be use it?

My code is here.

```js
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized(){
    // Find the element where the 3d viewer will live.    
    var htmlElement = document.getElementById('ViewerArea');
    if (htmlElement) {
        // Create and start the viewer in that element    
        var config = { "disableBrowserContextMenu" : false };
        viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlElement, config);
        viewer.start();
        // Load the document into the viewer.
        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
    }
});
```

From https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=7.14

```js
Viewer3D.prototype.initContextMenu = function() {
    // Disable the browser's default context menu by default, or if explicitly specified.
    //
    var disableBrowserContextMenu = !this.config || (this.config.hasOwnProperty("disableBrowserContextMenu") ? this.config.disableBrowserContextMenu : true);
    if (disableBrowserContextMenu) {
        this.onDefaultContextMenu = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        };
        this.container.addEventListener('contextmenu', this.onDefaultContextMenu, false);
    }
    var self = this;
    var canvas = this.canvas || this.container;
    this.onMouseDown = function(event) {
        if (EventUtils.isRightClick(event)) {
            self.startX = event.clientX;
            self.startY = event.clientY;
        }
    }
    canvas.addEventListener( 'mousedown', this.onMouseDown);
    this.onMouseUp = function(event) {
        if (EventUtils.isRightClick(event) && event.clientX === self.startX && event.clientY === self.startY) {
            self.triggerContextMenu(event);
        }
        return true;
    }
    canvas.addEventListener( 'mouseup', this.onMouseUp, false);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes `disableBrowserContextMenu` is a Viewer initialization/construction option to disable the built-in context menu that comes with Viewer and you are using it correctly with your code in the OP.

```
const config = {
   disableBrowserContextMenu:false
//...
}
new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(container,config)
```

We are working to improve the documentation comprehensively for our services in the next few months and I will let the team know to try fill out missing pieces like this.

Thanks for your helpful feedback!

Comment: Thank you! I got it.